# How can i specify the position of a videoview? (top left, top right, bottom left... etc )

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

i have a VideoView that i know how to center it on the screen, but now i need to specify dinamically (java code, not xml code) the position on the screen.

This is my actual code:

```
    VideoView vv = new VideoView(this);
    this.setContentView(vv);
    android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams vvParams = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) vv.getLayoutParams();
    vvParams.gravity=17; //gravity 17 = center horizontal & vertical
    vvParams.width=150;
    vv.setLayoutParams(vvParams);        
    String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.v;
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
    vv.start();
```

These are the possible positions i want to specify:

(vertical/horizontal)

- top left, top center, top right
- center left, center center, center right
- bottom left, bottom center, bottom right

How to specify these possitions with java code dinamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your VideoView the child of a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html), and then update the LayoutParams like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams();

// Horizontal alignment - choose as appropriate
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
//lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
//lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

// Vertical alignment - choose as appropriate
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
//lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
//lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

vv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```